# Group data into separate partitions based on identified NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to break a partition based on a NULL value as seen below in the 'GroupNumber' column.  The purpose is that within window function statements, there isn't another identifier within my dataset that could break the groups apart (e.g. seen below to derive the "GroupNumber" column).  The point is the create this "GroupNumber" column.  Is there a way to break/reset the partition when a NULL value exists (ordered by date DESC)?  Note: There can be multiple NULL instances for each partition. Any help is appreciated.

**METHODOLOGY:**

1. Create bit flag column to represent NULL values.
2. Use rolling sum (sorted by date DESC) to create these groups.  This is a great method because at each observed NULL value, the "GROUP" field would increment dynamically. This would allow for aggregate calculations using this new field as a partition.

**EXAMPLE SETUP:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#GroupNULL', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #GroupNULL

CREATE TABLE #GroupNULL
([ID] INT NOT NULL,
[Date] date NULL,
[Number] INT NULL)

INSERT INTO #GroupNULL (ID, Date, Number) VALUES (1001, '8/12/2018', 35)
INSERT INTO #GroupNULL (ID, Date, Number) VALUES (1001, '8/11/2018', 27)
INSERT INTO #GroupNULL (ID, Date, Number) VALUES (1001, '8/10/2018', 7)
INSERT INTO #GroupNULL (ID, Date, Number) VALUES (1001, '8/9/2018', 18)
INSERT INTO #GroupNULL (ID, Date, Number) VALUES (1001, '8/8/2018', NULL)
INSERT INTO #GroupNULL (ID, Date, Number) VALUES (1001, '8/7/2018', 3)
INSERT INTO #GroupNULL (ID, Date, Number) VALUES (1001, '8/6/2018', 42)
INSERT INTO #GroupNULL (ID, Date, Number) VALUES (1001, '8/5/2018', 16)
INSERT INTO #GroupNULL (ID, Date, Number) VALUES (1001, '8/4/2018', 9)
INSERT INTO #GroupNULL (ID, Date, Number) VALUES (1001, '8/3/2018', NULL)
```

FURTHER CONTEXT: I would like to partition this dataset into 2 groups, with the first NULL value (ordered by date DESC) to be the first value of the group.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Images of data are often frowned upon as the volunteers you're asking help from can't use it. Data should be posted as formatted `text` or as DDL and DML statements. What you appear to have here, however, is what's known as "Gaps and Islands", and there are plenty of examples on how to get the answer you're after. When asking a question, it's expected that you show your attempts as well, could you please post those when you edit your image to text please? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks and understood.  I feel that I've clarified my request and posted the solution for this to be taken off hold.  Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SETUP**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#GroupNULL', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #GroupNULL

CREATE TABLE #GroupNULL
([ID] INT NOT NULL,
[Date] date NULL,
[Number] INT NULL)

INSERT INTO #GroupNULL (ID, Date, Number) VALUES (1001, '8/12/2018', 35)
INSERT INTO #GroupNULL (ID, Date, Number) VALUES (1001, '8/11/2018', 27)
INSERT INTO #GroupNULL (ID, Date, Number) VALUES (1001, '8/10/2018', 7)
INSERT INTO #GroupNULL (ID, Date, Number) VALUES (1001, '8/9/2018', 18)
INSERT INTO #GroupNULL (ID, Date, Number) VALUES (1001, '8/8/2018', NULL)
INSERT INTO #GroupNULL (ID, Date, Number) VALUES (1001, '8/7/2018', 3)
INSERT INTO #GroupNULL (ID, Date, Number) VALUES (1001, '8/6/2018', 42)
INSERT INTO #GroupNULL (ID, Date, Number) VALUES (1001, '8/5/2018', 16)
INSERT INTO #GroupNULL (ID, Date, Number) VALUES (1001, '8/4/2018', 9)
INSERT INTO #GroupNULL (ID, Date, Number) VALUES (1001, '8/3/2018', NULL)
```

**SOLUTION**

```
SELECT  x.*, 
        SUM(Flagged) OVER(ORDER BY ID, Date DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS [GroupNumber] 
FROM
(SELECT *, 
        CASE    WHEN LAG(Number) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC) IS NULL 
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
        END AS [Flagged] 
FROM #GroupNULL) x

ID          Date       Number      Flagged     GroupNumber
----------- ---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1001        2018-08-12 35          1           1
1001        2018-08-11 27          0           1
1001        2018-08-10 7           0           1
1001        2018-08-09 18          0           1
1001        2018-08-08 NULL        0           1
1001        2018-08-07 3           1           2
1001        2018-08-06 42          0           2
1001        2018-08-05 16          0           2
1001        2018-08-04 9           0           2
1001        2018-08-03 NULL        0           2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that should get you pretty close.  It uses windowing aggregates to add up the number of NULLs you have seen in a given order of the table as returned in a query.  This works on recent versions of SQL Server/SQL Azure (SQL Server 2012+ I believe)

```
drop table t1
create table t1 (col1 int, col2 int)
insert into t1(col1, col2) values (1, 1)
insert into t1(col1, col2) values (1, 10)
insert into t1(col1, col2) values (2, NULL)
insert into t1(col1, col2) values (2, 10)
insert into t1(col1, col2) values (3, 2)
insert into t1(col1, col2) values (3, NULL)

SELECT
    col1, 
    col2,
    IsBoundary,
    SUM(IsBoundary) OVER(ORDER BY col1, col2 ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) + 1 as GroupNumber
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        col1, 
        col2,
        CASE WHEN col2 is NULL then 1 ELSE 0 END as IsBoundary
    FROM 
        t1
) A
ORDER BY col1, col2

col1        col2        IsBoundary  GroupNumber
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           0           1
1           10          0           1
2           NULL        1           2
2           10          0           2
3           NULL        1           3
3           2           0           3
```

Comment: Thanks Conor! This is very close to what I'm looking to achieve and gives me something to work with.  I've updated my post with the foundation table and I did get   the groupings as you've listed using:

SELECT x.*, 
  SUM(Flagged) OVER(ORDER BY ID, Date DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) + 1 AS [GroupNumber] 
FROM
(SELECT *, 
  CASE WHEN Number IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Flagged] FROM #GroupNULL) x

I'll try to work with your code to start each group at the NULL value

Comment: Got it!

SELECT x.*, 
  SUM(Flagged) OVER(ORDER BY ID, Date DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) + 1 AS [GroupNumber] 
FROM
(SELECT *, 
  CASE WHEN LAG(Number) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Flagged] FROM #GroupNULL) x